# KDB+ / Q Accessing root namespace from namespace

Tags: namespaces, kdb, q-lang

how can I access functions/variables in the root namespace once I jumped into another namespace.

Example like this:

```
q)\d .cfg
q)domIV:1000
q)\d .
q)n:1000
```

And then later on I know how to access the variable `domIV` from the other namespace, but I dont know how to access the variable `n` from there:

```
q)\d .seed
q).cfg.domIV / works
q)n          / does not work
q).n         / does also not work
```

How can I access the root namespace?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Context (namespace) is just a dictionary so you can use dictionary syntax.

```
      q)  \d .seed
      q.seed)   `.[`n]
```

Reference:  http://code.kx.com/q4m3/12_Workspace_Organization/

Check section:   A Context is a Dictionary

Comment: you can also use ``value `..n``